# Iterating a register?

Tags: arrays, assembly, iteration, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Let's say I have an array of 4 2 bytes long integers in memory.
I want to load my whole array into a simd register before performing read-only calculations.

```
leaq myArray,%rax // myArray being a 64bits long array of 4 2 bytes elements
movq 0(%rax),%xmm0 // low part of %xmm0 now contains my whole array
```

From memory, I would do :

```
movw 0(%rax),%cx // first element of array in memory
movw 2(%rax),%dx // second element of array in memory
movw 4(%rax),%r8w // third element of array in memory
movw 6(%rax),%r9w // last element of array in memory
```

But I want to do something like :

```
movw %xmm0[0],%cx // first element of %xmm0
movw %xmm0[2],%dx // first element of %xmm0
movw %xmm0[4],%r8w // first element of %xmm0
movw %xmm0[6],%r9w // first element of %xmm0
```

Is there a way to iterate through a register or to use the (base,offset,multiplier) directly on the content of the register?

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but maybe you are looking for `PINSRW`/`PEXTRW`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, I'll look into that. I have a loop which compares each element of my array with each other that I'm trying to optimize but it seems the most expensive operations are the memory fetches. I want to copy my array into registers so I can avoid fetching the array elements from memory every time I compare one of them.

Comment: You might want to use parallel comparisons then instead of copying the items into word registers. Sounds like an XY problem, you should specify what you really want to do.

Comment: Instead of `lea`, just use `movq myArray, %xmm0`.  You only need the address in an integer register if you want to walk a pointer through the array, or index it with another register.